# Bash Y/N prompt accepting also the ENTER key

Tags: linux, bash, prompt, user-interaction

I am trying to create a script a Y/n prompt in bash which in case of hitting the ENTER key to execute the script. So far I have created the script to accept only Yes/No answers and to read only the first letter and ignore the rest:

```
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to remove this directory [Y/n]? " rmv
    rmv=${rmv,,}                                 # lower the letters in the rmv variable
    case $rmv in
        [y]* ) echo "YES"; break;;
        #[] ) echo "Enter Key"; break;;
        [n]* ) echo "NO"; exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no! ";;   # repeat until valid answer
    esac
done
```

The idea is that in case of Y/y/yes/YES or Enter the script to execute some command, in case of No/N/n/no to break the loop and in case of invalid answer to ask the question again. I was thinking that the best will be to use OR "||" on the row with "Y" case.

Comment: You can also use the `read -ei Y` to make 'Y' the default response if nothing else is typed, although that then requires slightly more typing to provide a different response.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `case` statement, you can test for the empty string like this:

```
        "") echo "Enter Key"; break;;
```

Comment: yes, it works :) really simple, thanks a lot for your help!